# Fewer Rows from the XML depending upon the condition

Tags: xml

Currently I have following XML:

```
<Rowsets>
    <Rowset>
        <Row>
            <DrilldownDepth>0</DrilldownDepth>
            <ScheduleWeek>---</ScheduleWeek>
            <ABC>---</ABC>
            <PQR>1500</PQR>
            <XYZ>15000</XYZ>
            <Quant>285</Quant>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <DrilldownDepth>1</DrilldownDepth>
            <ScheduleWeek>12</ScheduleWeek>
            <ABC>---</ABC>
            <PQR>1500</PQR>
            <XYZ>15000</XYZ>
            <Quant>285</Quant>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <DrilldownDepth>2</DrilldownDepth>
            <ScheduleWeek>12</ScheduleWeek>
            <ABC>SUPER</ABC>
            <PQR>100</PQR>
            <XYZ>200</XYZ>
            <Quant>300</Quant>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <DrilldownDepth>2</DrilldownDepth>
            <ScheduleWeek>12</ScheduleWeek>
            <ABC>Duper</ABC>
            <PQR>100</PQR>
            <XYZ>200</XYZ>
            <Quant>300</Quant>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <DrilldownDepth>2</DrilldownDepth>
            <ScheduleWeek>12</ScheduleWeek>
            <ABC>Fun</ABC>
            <PQR>100</PQR>
            <XYZ>200</XYZ>
            <Quant>300</Quant>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <DrilldownDepth>2</DrilldownDepth>
            <ScheduleWeek>7</ScheduleWeek>
            <ABC>SUPER</ABC>
            <PQR>100</PQR>
            <XYZ>200</XYZ>
            <Quant>300</Quant>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <DrilldownDepth>2</DrilldownDepth>
            <ScheduleWeek>7</ScheduleWeek>
            <ABC>Duper</ABC>
            <PQR>100</PQR>
            <XYZ>200</XYZ>
            <Quant>300</Quant>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <DrilldownDepth>2</DrilldownDepth>
            <ScheduleWeek>8</ScheduleWeek>
            <ABC>SUPER</ABC>
            <PQR>100</PQR>
            <XYZ>200</XYZ>
            <Quant>300</Quant>
        </Row>
    </Rowset>
</Rowsets>
```

Now I need only those `<Row>` where `<DrilldownDepth>2</DrilldownDepth>` and  `<ScheduleWeek>12</ScheduleWeek>`. I can achieve it using a repeater/loop but I need to achieve it using either Xpath or XSLT. So any help inthis matter will be appreciated.

Sots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following XPath statement uses a [predicate](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#predicates) filter to select the Row elements that contain the child elements that meet the specified criteria:

```
/Rowsets/Rowset/Row[DrilldownDepth=2 and ScheduleWeek=12]
```

Using variables for the values applied in XSLT:

```
<xsl:variable name="depth">2</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="week">12</xsl:variable>
<xsl:apply-templates select="/Rowsets/Rowset/Row[DrilldownDepth=$depth and ScheduleWeek=$week]"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Hansen. But can this be achieved using XSLT or XQUERY where "2" and "12" are passed via Variables?

Comment: Yes. Substitute the variables for the values

Comment: Currently I'm trying XSLT:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" exclude-result-prefixes="java" version="1.0">
<xsl:output media-type="text/xml" method="xml"/>
<xsl:variable name="depth">2</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="week">12</xsl:variable>
<xsl:template match="/Rowsets">
 <Rowsets>
 <xsl:for-each select= "Rowset[ Row[DrilldownDepth=$depth and ScheduleWeek=$week] ]">
 

   <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
 </xsl:for-each>
 </Rowsets>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet> Not working

Comment: You are iterating over the `Rowset` elements with a predicate filter selecting the `Rowset` elements that contain `Row` elements that contain the `DrilldownDepth` and `SecheduleWeek` and then copying the `Rowset` element (which contains all of those `Row` elements). If you only want the `Row` elements that match your criteria, you need to select them, not the `Rowset`.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the 'and' operator is to use a second predicate. Which is better is down to personal style, but if you look over a lot of answers on SO, you will see that the multiple predicate method is the popular choice.

It looks like this ...

```
 /Rowsets/Rowset/Row[DrilldownDepth='2'][ScheduleWeek='12']
```

**Note:** This works equally well with or without quote marks around the literal numbers. Without might be slightly more readable. With may be slightly more efficient. Again this is a style choice.

Comment: Thanks Sean. But can this be achieved using XSLT or XQUERY where "2" and "12" are passed via Variables?